# Apache Wordpress & Flask mod_wsgi Same Domain

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi

I have Flask running under Apache via mod_wsgi with a trigger at `andrewtclaus.com/TDAA_reminder`. That works fine. But to get that to work, I had to break my normal webpage `andrewtclaus.com` by messing up the server name in the `.conf` file. How do I get both of them running at the same time when the two `.conf` need to have the same address? I tried adding `/hook` or my actual hook/app `\TDAA_reminder` the the first `.conf` but then my python script doesn't run. Apache error logs show nothing.

mod_wsgi/hook:

```
ServerName AndrewTClaus.com
ServerAdmin admin@andrewtclaus.com
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/TDAA_reminder/TDAA_reminder.wsgi
<Directory /var/www/TDAA_reminder/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
Alias /static /var/www/TDAA_reminder/TDAA_reminder/static
<Directory /var/www/TDAA_reminder/TDAA_reminder/static/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

and wordpress:

```
ServerAdmin admin@AndrewTClaus.com
ServerName AndrewTClaus.com
ServerAlias www.AndrewTClaus.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/AndrewTClaus
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/AndrewTClaus>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

Edited them together as I think was recommend, got Apache to restart but can only get either the hook/WSGI or the website to work by playing with this code. What am I missing?

```
    ServerAdmin admin@AndrewTClaus.com
    ServerName AndrewTClaus.com
    ServerAlias www.AndrewTClaus.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/AndrewTClaus

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/AndrewTClaus>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/TDAA_reminder/TDAA_reminder.wsgi
    <Directory /var/www/TDAA_reminder/>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Comment: What do you mean you had to mess up the server name? When you use ``WSGIScriptAlias`` directive for mod_wsgi at a sub URL it should overlay the existing application. That is, only requests for the sub URL should go to the WSGI application and everything else should still go to whatever you already had running in the ``VirtualHost``. So just add the mod_wsgi configuration to the existing ``VirtualHost``.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I added "xx" to the server name and alias to break the link. I also updated my OP to add the 2 `.conf` files

Comment: Ass I said, add the mod_wsgi stuff to the existing ``VirtualHost`` where Wordpress is. As WSGI application at sub URL, should be good. For more complicated PHP+mod_wsgi configurations read: http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/hosting-php-web-applications-in.html

Comment: Ah thanks @GrahamDumpleton I think it got it now. A single `.conf` for both of them. I have 2 right now. Does it matter where I put the WSGI stuff before or after the rest?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I got them combined, but I still only get either WSGI or wordpress working depending on if I add some text. I can get the website working by breaking WSGI by adding something after WSGIScriptAlias `WSGIScriptAlias /TDAA_reminder`. What am I missing?

Comment: Go read that blog post. You have now changed things to try and have WSGI application at root of the site instead of a sub URL. If you want that you can't use ``WSGIScriptAlias``. The blog post explains what to do in that situation.

Comment: Thanks @GrahamDumpleton. Article was a little above my head but posted on there. I was able to use a sub URL "hook' to solve my particular issue `WSGIScriptAlias /hook /var/www/TDAA_reminder/TDAA_reminder.wsgi`